# Multiple messages exchange in python socket network

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, networking

This is my simple program for asking input basis on news options :

```
from newsapi.articles import Articles
import sys


a=Articles('cff9541f3b5a4558957e63ea59b3743b')
#key is working you can use it for testing 

def news_choice():
    options = ['news', 'jokes', 'life_style']
    print(options)
    print('\n')
    print('------------------------------')
    inpu = input("what do you want? ")             #input_1
    if inpu == 'news':
        print([k for i in a.get_by_popular(source='techcrunch')['articles'] for k in i])
        print('\n')
        print('------------------------------')

        inpu = input(
            'Which option would you like to select : description , author , url , urlToImage , title, publishedAt ')   #input_2
        print([i[inpu] for i in a.get_by_popular(source='techcrunch')['articles']])

        inpu = input("would you like to quit ? yes | No ")  #input_3
        if inpu == 'yes':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            news_choice()
news_choice()
```

output is :

```
['news', 'jokes', 'life_style']


------------------------------
what do you want? news
['urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description']


------------------------------
Which option would you like to select : description , author , url , urlToImage , title, publishedAt title
['Huawei’s Richard Yu is really pissed at US\xa0carriers', 'H-1B visa extensions for workers waiting on green cards are safe for\xa0now', 'Kodak announces ICO, stock jumps\xa044%', 'Razer moves into wireless power, debuts HyperFlux mouse and\xa0pad']
would you like to quit ? yes | No yes

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now i want to make my script as sever and anyone can connect to my script via telnet so i have this server and client script :

```
import socket
import threading
import last_commit
class ThreadedServer(object):
    dict_cache={}



    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port


        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):

        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            print("client post is {}".format(address[1]))
            self.dict_cache['client']=address[1]
            print(self.dict_cache)
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1000000
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    da_1= str(data,'utf-8')


                    # Set the response to echo back the recieved data

                    reply=last_commit.chat_bot_reply(da_1).encode()

                    client.send(reply)
                    tmp_dict = {"customer": da_1, "bot": reply}
                    if address[0] not in self.dict_cache:
                        self.dict_cache[address[0]]=[tmp_dict]
                    else:
                        self.dict_cache[address[0]].append(tmp_dict)

                    print(self.dict_cache)



                else:
                    raise Exception('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

while True:
    port_num = input("Port? ")
    try:
        port_num = int(port_num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

ThreadedServer('', port_num).listen()
```

Now i have modified above script to make my script as server like this:

```
import socket
import threading
from newsapi.articles import Articles
import sys
class ThreadedServer(object):
    dict_cache={}



    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port


        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):

        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            print("client post is {}".format(address[1]))
            self.dict_cache['client']=address[1]
            print(self.dict_cache)
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1000000
        client.send('Hi,Welcome to Apolo fun'.encode())
        while True:
            try:

                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    da_1= str(data,'utf-8')




                    a = Articles('cff9541f3b5a4558957e63ea59b3743b')

                    def news_choice():
                        options = ['news', 'jokes', 'life_style']
                        client.send(b'working')
                        client.send(options.encode())
                        client.send(b'\n')
                        client.send(b'------------------------------')
                        data_1 = client.recv(size)
                        if data_1 == 'news':
                            client.send([k for i in a.get_by_popular(source='techcrunch')['articles'] for k in i].encode())
                            client.send('\n'.encode())
                            client.send('------------------------------'.encode())
                            data_2 = client.recv(size)


                            print([i[data_2] for i in a.get_by_popular(source='techcrunch')['articles']])

                            data_3 = client.recv(size)
                            if data_3 == 'yes':
                                sys.exit()
                            else:
                                news_choice()

                    news_choice()




                else:
                    raise Exception('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

while True:
    port_num = input("Port? ")
    try:
        port_num = int(port_num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

ThreadedServer('', port_num).listen()
```

And my client script is :

```
import socket

import time
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = int(input("Server port? "))
sock.connect((host,port))
while True:
    print("response: ", sock.recv(1024))
    data = input("message: ")
    sock.send(data.encode())
    print("response: ", sock.recv(1024))
    print("response: ", sock.recv(1023))
    print("response: ", sock.recv(1023))
    print("response: ", sock.recv(1023))
```

Now as you can see there are three input in my origional script and my main confusion is server client is working on message--> responce --> message --> responce senerio so if i receieve any message from client how i will determine this message is for which input and it can break scope of function , like for example if i need input_2 which is in scope of news_api output and now if i got any message from client how i will put that output at place of input_2 .

if it is confusing then then my conclusion is I want  expected output via server client is same like this , How can i convert my original program into server and let anyone connect via that client script

```
['news', 'jokes', 'life_style']


------------------------------
what do you want? news
['urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description', 'urlToImage', 'title', 'publishedAt', 'author', 'url', 'description']


------------------------------
Which option would you like to select : description , author , url , urlToImage , title, publishedAt title
['Huawei’s Richard Yu is really pissed at US\xa0carriers', 'H-1B visa extensions for workers waiting on green cards are safe for\xa0now', 'Kodak announces ICO, stock jumps\xa044%', 'Razer moves into wireless power, debuts HyperFlux mouse and\xa0pad']
would you like to quit ? yes | No yes
```

Comment: what output do you have now?

Comment: You can run the script which i provided there , the key is workin so you will get idea , bdw i am getting very strange output like empty bytes.